# Get list of Facebook events that user is an admin of

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the Facebook Graph API and would like to get a list of events that a user is an admin of. `/me/events` gives a list of events that the user is attending. `/me/accounts` gives a list of pages that the user is an admin of.

Is there a way of doing this? The docs are atrocious.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the `event_id` (and of course an appropriate access token), you can make a request to the following endpoint:

```
EVENT_ID/admins
```

Strangely enough this endpoint doesn't seem to appear in the documentation. I wouldn't really trust that this endpoint will remain active. It does currently, however, yield results for me.

Comment: But I don't have the event ID...that's what I'm trying to find. The only way to do it this way would be to loop through all possible event IDs, get the admins and then check them against the user. This would be a little inefficient to say the least!

Comment: You can get a list of events by the endpoint that you mentioned... `user/events`. This is the only way that you  can get event ID's that are related (somehow) to the user.

Comment: I agree that it is not very efficient to make multiple requests but it seems Facebook has decided not to create an appropriate endpoint for this query... you are still able to get to that data though...the long way round :P

Comment: Can't this be requested with field expansion like this: /me?fields=events{id,name,admins}

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to Lix' question as well. This seems to be the most efficient way to do it, as states in the comments to that question:

> Can't this be requested with field expansion like this:
>   /me?fields=events{id,name,admins}

This way you get all events and its admins. Now you can loop through all the events and admins to check whether the user is one or not, all with just 1 query.